# how to implement find search functionality using kendo-ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am new to kendo ui development. I am trying to implement a find box like eclipse where I can search kendo-grid data values like Find Next, Find Previous, Wrap Search,Case Sensitive and Whole word. If word is found in search than it should change background colour to yellow(like in Chrome browser).

I tried using *[this](http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/@kashyapa/IhEr/5)* but I am still unable to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in filterRow functionality?

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

Comment: Yes I tried, In case of filter its displaying only matching row but I need to display all the rows and first matching occurrence should be highlighted and focused.